# Breeze much slower after updating to EF 6 and breeze 1.4.6

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, breeze

I've noticed that breeze 1.4.6 + EF 6 is much slower than older version of breeze + EF 5
The code is completely same, and here are screenshots of my requests (first is with older versions):

[image]

[image]

I've noticed that text is unreadable, in order to read it right-click on image, show image in new tab.

Why is this happening ? (I've cleared cache several times, tested in different browsers etc.)

**EDIT**

Today I've found time to play with this problem, but I couldn't get to bottom of it, I've created Test project with 6 entities, here are examples for two most complex entities:

```
public class Exercise
    {
        public int ExerciseId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public  ICollection<ExerciseLevel> ExerciseLevels { get; set; }

    }

public class ExerciseLevel
    {
        public int LevelId { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public int ExerciseId { get; set; }
        public Exercise Exercise { get; set; }

    }
```

And they are configured with fluent API, for example:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Exercise>()
            .HasMany(e => e.ExerciseLevels)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Exercise)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.ExerciseId);
```

I have only one breeze controller:

```
 [BreezeController]
    public class ServiceController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly EFContextProvider<DatabaseTest> _contextProvider = new EFContextProvider<DatabaseTest>();

        [HttpGet]
        public string Metadata()
        {
            return _contextProvider.Metadata();
        }

        // GET api/<controller>
        [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<MuscleGroup> MuscleGroups()
        {
            return _contextProvider.Context.MuscleGroups;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<Muscle> Muscles()
        {
            return _contextProvider.Context.Muscles;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
        {
            return _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
        }
    }
```

And when I enter URL: breeze/Service/Metadata it takes about 3000 ms to complete. Pic is below:

[image]

I have no idea why is this happening :(

Comment: What makes you think this is an issue with Breeze?  Have you stepped through your server side operations to find out what is taking so long???

Comment: Well I have, and for example  as you can see request  breeze/service/Metadata takes about 5.5 to complete, and all other queries are much faster, I've used stopwatch on server to calculate how long will it take to calculate `_contextProvider.Metadata()` and got similar result, if this is not problem with breeze, what else could be problem ?

Comment: I want to stress out that my models are same in both cases, fluent api is same, etc. (everything is same, except version of EF and breeze), so in newer environment call breeze/Service/Metadata takes 14 480 ms, and is around 40kB, in older environment, same call, 1 646 ms, and is about 47kb

Comment: We don't see this in any of our internal tests. I think you may have something else going on. Please post back if you figure out what it is. I am curious.

Comment: I've created test project with two classes, ef 6 (+ FluentApi) + breeze 1.4.6, breeze/Service/Metadata takes around 130 ms, for 2,45 kb not sure if that's good or not

Comment: @PWKad Please can you see my updated question ?